# how to get user follower detail with Periscope API in php

Tags: api

How can i get periscope followers for the particular user by using user id or username with the help of periscope API.

i have try below periscope api library to get followers but not get any result.

https://github.com/aliosmanyuksel/periscopr-api

please help me.